# Control de permisos en aplicación Android hecha con Phonegap

Tags: android, phonegap, android-manifest

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Android con Phonegap y quiero controlar los permisos que pide la aplicación al instalarse, pero no consigo hacerlo. Desde el `config.xml` no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, pero desde el `AndroidManifest.xml` si que he encontrado la sección de permisos, pero borro permisos o añado de nuevos, compilo y construyo la app pero a la hora de instalarse siempre me aparece como que tiene los mismos permisos.

Por ejemplo, en el `AndroidManifest.xml` he añadido este nuevo permiso, para probar solamente:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />`

E intento instalar la aplicación pero en la lista de permisos o accesos que necesita o utiliza la app, no me aparece este nuevo de recibir sms. O elimino permisos, y al instalar no han desaparecido de la lista.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo en el `config.xml`? ¿O cual sería la manera correcta de hacerlo en el `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Con añadir los permisos al `Manifest.xml` no es suficiente. Existen algunos permisos que son necesarios declararlos al iniciar la actividad para que al usuario le salte un mensaje y pueda dar dichos permisos.

Necesitarias añadir al método `onCreate` de tu `MainActivity.java` el siguiente código.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (!(checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 1);
            }
        }
```

Esto comprueba que si la versión de SDK del dispositivo es mayor a 23 (ya que en las versiones anteriores no hace falta dar permisos), chequee si la aplicación tiene o no el permiso de recibir mensajes. En caso de no tenerlos hace un request mostrando al usuario un mensaje para que garantice los permisos.

Si tuvieras más permisos deberías de comprobarlos de la misma manera.

Comment: Pero todos los otros permisos que si que salen en la lista al instalar la app, solo están en el `Manifest.xml`, no están declarados de ninguna forma en el MainActivity ni nada. Yo lo que quiero más que nada es eliminar permisos y que no aparezcan en la app en la pantalla esta de "Instalar" - "Cancelar".

Comment: A partir de android 6.0 este es el método que se debe utilizar para pedir los permisos. Probablemente tengas un documento donde también pidas los permisos al instalar con algún plugin como el de cordova. Pero deberías de quitar esos permisos.